# Silverstripe 4 themedir not working while take image from theme folder

Tags: silverstripe-4

Function `$ThemeDir` is not working in  silverstripe template while using with img html tag for example

```
<img src="$ThemeDir/img/slides/2.jpg" alt="" />
```

Comment: <img src="$ThemeDir/img/slides/2.jpg" alt="" />

Answer (score 0):

ThemeDir was removed in SilverStripe 4 but it looks like it will be added back very soon.

[Source for removal](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/commit/9d35ff8f9559ae7087ce189880db749fe1569efa)

[Source for restore](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/pull/7626)